# set some custom csss styles in Leadpages

Tags: css, border

I can't set the bvoders , shadows of fonts, and the position fixing.

I tried css tab in Style panel but it doesn't work.
I can't set the bvoders , shadows of fonts, and the position fixing.

I tried css tab in Style panel but it doesn't work.
I can't set the bvoders , shadows of fonts, and the position fixing.

I tried css tab in Style panel but it doesn't work.
I can't set the bvoders , shadows of fonts, and the position fixing.

Comment: Why repeat the same thing multiple times?